# Riemann integration of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f$ be integrable convex function on $[a,b]$. Prove
>   $$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f\, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Intuitively, I see that this means the value of the function at the center of the interval is at most the average value of the function. The right-hand side is equal to $f(c)$ for some $c \in [a,b]$. From convexity,
$$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2} (f(a) + f(b)),$$
which is the average value of the function evaluated at the end-points. I would appreciate just a **small** hint please, **no answers**.

Comment: There's a whole lot more inequalities of the form $f((a+b)/2)\le\frac12(f(?)+f(??))$ available...

Comment: To put name on things, this is one direction of the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality). (The link contains no proof, so it will not spoil your work, since you only wanted hints, and no solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove that for $h \in \big[0,\frac{b-a}{2}\big)$ $$2\, f\big(\frac{a + b}{2}\big) \le f\Big(\frac{a + b}{2} + h\Big) + f\Big(\frac{a + b}{2} - h\Big)$$

Comment: This sort of defeats the purpose of the problem...

Comment: @Nitin: I see your point, I edited with what I think is a better hint. let me know what you think! :)